# "Approved" ? on technical data sheet

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm translating a technical data sheet in Excel which employees use to record parameters from a particular working machine.

Next to the parameters there's a column where at the end of the day they have to put their signature.

The name of the column can be roughly translated as "seen". I was thinking maybe "approved" could be a decent translation but I was wondering if there's a better term.

Comment: Will "approve with signature" be too long?

Comment: Would "validated" or "checked" or just "inspected" work?

Comment: Since they are adding the actual values and not just viewing/approving them, what about "logged?"

Answer (score 1):

A few possibilities:

**Confirmed**. Confirm: to give new assurance of the validity of.

**Accepted**. Accept: to give admittance or approval to.

**Verified**. Verify: to prove, show, find out, or state that (something) is true or correct.

**Validated**. Validate: to confirm the validity of.